# Anaconda Navigator (1.9.7) Stuck in offline mode - Mac

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, python-3.7, offline

My anaconda navigator app seems to be stuck on offline mode. I have tried different methods that i have read online but nothing seems to fix the problem. It just says that it is working in offline mode. I tried turning off the firewall, restarting the app, even updating the distro but nothing seems to work so far...

The only thing i didn't try (since i couldn't figure out how to do it on a mac) is opening port 53 to the host="8.8.8.8" as suggested on [github](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10176), but i am not sure if this would work since turning off my firewall didn't seem to fix the issue.

I am using Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7 on a Mac OS 10.14.16 Mojave and Python 3.7.4

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open anaconda-navigator and go to Preferences, there is a switch to disable off-line mode. See image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: if my answer was correct would you please click on the checkmark near my answer?